# Adding bitmap received from server to an image gridview in android

Tags: android, imageview, base64, android-gridview, android-bitmap

I have an android code which receives images as base64 string from the server in the form of json data. The code is given below. After receiving the images I have to decode the images as bitmap. And after that I have to display that images in an image gridview. How can this acheived? please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.mygallery;

//skipping the import section
public class Gallery extends Activity 
{

    int refresh=0;
    Bitmap decodedByte;
    GridView gridView;
    String username,password,count1,status;
    int count;
    ArrayList<String>imagearraylist;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("My_login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        username=sp.getString("username", "");
        password=sp.getString("password", "");
        new serverconnection().execute();


    }

    public class serverconnection extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try
            {
                String link="http://tonyjoseph.site90.com/sendimage.php"; 
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");  
                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter (conn.getOutputStream()); 
                wr.write( data );
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String line = null; // Read Server Response 
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                { 
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                String status=sb.toString();
                JSONObject jsonResponse1;

                try 
                {

                    /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                    jsonResponse1 = new JSONObject(status);

                    /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. Returns null otherwise.*******/
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode=jsonResponse1.optJSONArray("Android");


                    /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/
                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

                    Log.d("Json Array Length",String.valueOf(lengthJsonArr));


                    for(int j1=0;j1<lengthJsonArr;j1++)
                    {
                        Context mContext;
                        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(j1);

                        /******* Fetch node values **********/
                        String index=jsonChildNode.optString("index").toString();
                        String imagename=jsonChildNode.optString("imagename").toString();

                        //Here I get the images from server as string one after another
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imagename, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                        // At this stage I will be getting a list of bitmapsfrom the server which is converted from the received json
                        // i need to display these bitmaps into a image grid view ie display the images as a grid
                        // how can this be acheived??


                    }

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.print(ex);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "Loading complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pd.dismiss();

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(Gallery.this);
            pd.setTitle("Loading images..");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Follow http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/748050-how-to-set-up-a-list-of-clickable-images-in-android-app-development-with-gridview

Comment: This is not the one which I was looking for...My image bitmaps are not saved to anywhere in the sdcard. So loading from the sdcard is not possible. I need to display each image one after the another instantly after converting the image from base64 string to bitmap in the for loop of my code. Is it possible??

Comment: You can't modify any views from the "doInBackground" Method. that means you can't directly set the Bitmap image to any views (Grid View or Image View).  But you can create another Async task and pass the image as a parameter. and in that Async task's onPostExecute you can set the images to the View.

Comment: Your explanation at start and your code are confusing/contradictory. You explained that the received json would contain base64 encoded bitmaps. But reading your code you receive base64 encoded filenames. Which you decode to a byte array. If it was a name then it had to be decoded to a String. But then you apply bitmap factory on the byte array. Now if your comment would read "Now at this stage i have the bitmap in decodedByte" the scenario would be more clear. Please explain. What is the type of decodedByte? Oh i see. Don't call a bitmap like that please.

Comment: @naveejr indeed not in doInBackground. But no need to start a new async task. He can use the actual onPostExecute. Hmmmm.. Except you also thought that it was only an image name and the image had yet to be downloaded. But then use name or url please.

Comment: @greenapps His requirement is to show each images immediately once they are decoded. but onpostExecute will execute only after all the images are decoded.

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct. I oversaw. But starting a new async task in doInBackground? Is that a good idea? Will that work? Did you do that before? Maybe runOnUiThread will suit.

Comment: @naveejr As you have said I know that I can't display images to an image view or grid view inside an async task -doinbackground method. But Is there any way to display the decoded bitmaps...Please help me...

Comment: @TeeJay I'm confused with your requirement. were you able to properly decode the Bitmap image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that stage use `runOnUiThread` to place the received Bitmap 'in the grid'. But if you do not first save or cache all received bitmaps the grid will loose them with UI updates. The actual `placing in the grid` will be done by `getView()` calls after notify dataset changed.

Actually you do not need runOnUiThread at all. Just in doInBackGround save all images to a specific folder. Then in onPostExecute do a notifyDataSetChanged. The listview knows to retrieve from that folder.

Comment: Can you please explain little more?

Comment: I can explain a lot more of course. But i like you to first tell exactly a which point you need help. Did you ever place images in a grid before?

Comment: Then first start completing this code to save all received images to a folder. Then take the example from naveejr link. That example loads from resources but is adaptable to load from sdcard. Anyhow it is a good exercise. If you do a little search on this site you will also find examples which load from sdcard.

Comment: This example loads from a specific folder, just what you need: http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2012/07/gridview-loading-photos-from-sd-card.html

Comment: In my app,I donot want to save images to sd card. It is an personalized online gallery.The user can register an account in the server using the app and he can login to the server. The user can upload any number of images to the server from his phone. The images are converted to base64 string and send to the server as string. At the server,the images are stored in mysql database as text in the database.Then when the user uses the same app on other mobiles and login to the server,then he should see the same uploaded images. The user is asked whether to save the images on the sd card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56879/discussion-between-tee-jay-and-greenapps).